# Symfony2 - How to use multiple controllers in one route?

Tags: symfony, routes, entity

I have a big project, for a European website, so I need to manage multiple communities separately like France, England, Spain, and manage a platform type (3 possibilities : P1, P2, P3).

Someone told me that I need to create an entity `Community` which manages a country and the platform. But how to use others entities for my different routes?

For example, a user chooses his platform (P2) and his country (Spain). The route will be: xxx.com/p1/spain/ and he will be brought to the community page of his platform and country.
And now, I need to use a general entity to "create" the website which is common to all platform and country.
Example: xxx.com/p1/spain/content will be similar to xxx.com/p2/france/content

Spain needs to see content of Spain, and France need to see content of France, but the structure of the different communities is the same.

And sure, countries are dynamic, we can add more if we need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define routes like this:

```
some/route/{platform}/{country}/
```

In the controller retrieve content specific to platform and country.